# Saving Script vs onEdit trigger - why are they different?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to fire the following function on spreadsheet update (ideally, any change to Column A).  Basically, the script passes a name and the active cell's bgcolor.  If the name in a cell row matches the name passed, and the row color matches that active cell color, it adds one to redCount and returns this count.

My code works when the 'Save' button is clicked in the script editor (values are updated), but does not work with Google's Triggers (time-driven, 'From spreadsheet') or even when it's hard coded using onEvent(e).  Why is clicking the save button in the script editor handling the function execution differently from the Triggers, and how do I fix it?

```
/**
 * The number of times an Editor's Name appears on a red background.
 * @param {string} bgColour - A cell with the background colour we wish to track.
 * @param {string} editorName - The Editor's Name in quotation marks: "James".
 * @return The number of times an Editor's Name appears on a red background.
 * @customfunction
 */

function countSpreads(editorName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(1,2, lastRow-1);
  var actCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var activeBg = actCell.getBackground();
  var redCount = 0;
  var bgColors = searchRange.getBackgrounds();

  //Get array of values in the search Range
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  // Loop through array and if condition met +1 to redCount
  for (j = 0 ;j < lastRow - 1; j++){
    if(rangeValues[j] == editorName && bgColors[j] == activeBg){
      redCount++;
    }
  };
  return redCount;  
}
```

Comment: Clicking the save button doesn't trigger an execution? Also calling this function from a timed trigger would leave editorName undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the note about a timed trigger (this makes sense).  To your question, the Save button in the script editor DOES trigger an execution, but I can't get it fire when the spreadsheet is updated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason might be that both getValues() and getBackgrounds() methods return a 2-d array. So, in your 'for' loop, when you call rangeValues[j], assuming the cell has value 'editorName', it would return '[editorName]' with the brackets and not 'editorName', and similarly for backgrounds. This maybe causing your 'if' condition to return false.

Comment: The script executes just fine and returns values correctly on spreadsheet open.  It's just that cell values do not update when a trigger is fired.

Comment: Then I think you are going to have to provide more details about how your countSpreads function is called from your Triggers. Maybe it's the function that passes editorName to countSpreads that is causing the issue?

Comment: I really can't explain it, but after deleting the trigger a few times and re-creating it, the trigger finally started working.  No idea why!  No change to the codebase whatsoever.  Very frustrating, but glad it's finally triggering correctly.

Comment: Haha. Good to hear that!